# A way to return multiple return values from a method: put method inside class representing return value. Is it a good design?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need to return 2 values from a method. My approach is as follows:

1. create an inner class with 2 fields that will be used to keep those 2 values
2. put the method inside that class
3. instantiate the class and call the method.

The only thing that will be changed in the method is that in the end it will assign those 2 values to the fields of the instance. Then I can address those values by referencing to the fields of that object.

Is it a good design and why?

Comment: Another option (probably a bad one): see `BitInteger[] java.math.BigInteger.divideAndRemainder(BitInteger val)`.  It returns 2 integers as its return values in an array.

Comment: What type are the two values you want to return ?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668186/retuning-multiple-values-from-java-function-with-out-using-collection-as-a-retur .

Answer (score 15):

I would argue this along the following lines:

- Why exactly does your method return multiple values?  What kind of cohesion are we talking about - should those values actually be fields on a single class, or are they just coincidentally returned by the same method, but otherwise unrelated?  If it's the latter, you might want to consider splitting the method into two methods, rather.  Edit: use your judgement here; sometimes a type of "coincidental" cohesion may be the best option.  Another option is to use a pair or tuple construct, although in OOP, these are usually not seen in public APIs (some notable exceptions being standard collections, etc).
- If the values do deserve to form a class, I would probably advise against using an inner class.  Inner classes are typically used as internal implementation details, which are hidden from the outside.  Is there any reason why this result shouldn't be a "full-blown" class, in its own right?
- Other than holding data, what operations are applicable to this new class?  In object oriented design, you want to have the related behaviour close to the relevant data (which seem to be your intentions, too).  Should the method you are referring to not live on this class rather?

To summarise, I would see if I can turn this "data object" into a fledged-out class with both data and behaviour.  As an additional comment, you may want to make the class immutable, since its state is set once.  Making it immutable will help prevent it being incorrectly set, or modified later (say, someone setting one of the fields to null and passing it along).

Edit: As Patkos Csaba correctly points out, the principle being applied here is the Single Responsibility Principle ([SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)) - the class you are trying to create should really have one responsibility (defined as a *reason for changing*).  This design guideline should help you figure out whether your two fields belong in a single class, or not.  To stick with the Wikipedia example, your class could be a seen as a type of report, in which case it's conforming to SRP, but it's difficult to comment without further information.

Comment: While I agree with the general idea of this answer, there are legitimate cases when two closely related pieces of data are calculated together, but there's no sense to tie them together otherwise anywhere else in the program. In such a case it may be clean enough to return something like `Pair<OneClass, AnotherClass>`. Some people would [disagree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java). In any case, `Pair` should be an implementation detail and never appear in a public API method.

Comment: @9000 I agree; I actually meant the word *consider* to be taken literally in this case, i.e. splitting the method may not always be the best solution, it's just a rough indication in that direction.  I'll make an edit along those lines.

Comment: Good answer. The only thing I would add is a reference to the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). If checked, it is very possible that the method in discussion is just a simple violation of SRP and a split is a simple solution. In my experience, whenever a method wants to return 2 or more values, in 90% of the cases there are 2 methods there or another class should be extracted.

Comment: @PatkosCsaba thanks, made an edit to include it.  I normally stick to explaining things in terms of coupling and cohesion, but I guess the SOLID principles are seen as the basic rules to live by these days.

Comment: @DanielB: I see SOLID as higher level and probably easier to understand concepts. Coupling and cohesion are still the baseline, but they are more lower level. SOLID makes great use of coupling and cohesion to explain it's principles and to present them on a more generic level.

Comment: @PatkosCsaba I agree, and I think you're right about SOLID being easier to understand.  I guess I've stuck to the low-level stuff because it's the route I took to learn OOP.

Comment: @9000: If a class should have a public method to e.g. return the minimum and maximum values in a collection (computing both in one pass will very often be at least 25% faster than computing them separately, and could be almost 50% faster), how could `MinMaxPair` be an "implementation detail" as opposed to being part of the public API?

Comment: @supercat: If you have to return several values, do create a class (better yet, an interface) that describes exactly these. I mean, `MinMaxPair<T>` (with `.getMin` and `.getMax`) is a good approach, while `Pair<T, T>` is not. The latter can't even show the order (min, max vs max, min). Then, when you add mean and stddev calculation, you can extend `MinMaxPair<T>` to some `ListStats<T>` to include these new fields. With `Pair<T, T>`, you're stuck.

Comment: @9000: I appreciate that there are some advantages to using a type especially for a particular purpose, but having to create and document another `.class` file for every type whose semantics are nothing more than "each field contains whatever was put there" seems rather icky.  What I'd really like to see would be a means by which a method could be declared as returning `{double min,double max}`, an invocation could be written as `{minReading,maxReading} = readings.getMinMax()`, and the compiler would rewrite that as:

Comment: @9000: `minReading = reading.getMinMax(); maxReading = longBitsToDouble(currentThread.longTemp0);`.  Such a feature could be supported for small aggregations by adding a few `long` and `object` variables to `Thread`, without any changes to the JVM; it could in many cases offer much better performance than having to instantiate a new object instance on every call.

Comment: @supercat: What I care about at this moment is cleanliness and correctness of the interface. The actual packaging of data that allows to squeeze the last tiny droplet of performance is a valid but secondary concern. See "premature optimization".

Comment: @9000: If the purpose of a function is to compute and return two primitive values, I would suggest that the cleanest and most "correct" thing for it to do would be to return two primitive values if Java provided a way to do that.  Returning a reference to a newly-created immutable object may be the closest one can get in today's Java, but a method returning an object reference cannot avoid exposing implementation details such as whether two calls yielding the same values end up sharing the same instance.  Semantically, if a method should return two primitives, it should return two primitives.

Comment: @supercat: Unfortunately, Java does not seem to have a way to return two primitives without any scaffolding (like Forth would). Among possible types of scaffolding, I prefer the specially-crafted, well defined scaffolding to generic, error-prone scaffolding. Given enough performance constraints, you could consider packing two ints in creative ways, but then you'd be better off with a different language probably. [Value types for Java would be nice](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jrose/values/values-0.html), though; keep an eye on OpenJDK.

Comment: @9000: What I would like to see would be for the *language* to include a feature that would make use of a few extra fields in `Thread` to provide a means of efficiently returning multiple values.  The only Runtime feature necessary for this to work would be some fields; no JVM changes would be needed.  Using an immutable class might be the best possible way to return multiple values in the existing Framework, but that doesn't mean the Framework and language shouldn't cooperate to provide a better way.

Comment: @supercat: What you vouch for, as far as I understand, is some form of thread-local stack (else you'd not be able to handle nested calls) based on pre-allocated primitive storage. E.g you could use something like a `ThreadLocal<int[]>` for that. While in some situations this may be useful, I'd expressly avoid to make this detail a part of a general-purpose API. To quote the obligatory Hoare, as quoted by Knuth: _«We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil»_.

Comment: @9000: What I'd like to see would be for application-level code to specify its API as `{double min, double max} GetMinAndMax();`, and for the Java bytecode standard to indicate how that should be handled.  If the JVM later adds a better means of support (e.g. the ability to have methods leave some of the passed-in data in the stack), the spec could require that methods using the new format have a mangled name, and generate stubs to allow interaction between code expecting the old and new conventions.  Application code wouldn't concern itself with the thread variables.

Answer (score 10):

There's the concept of a Tuple which is featured in other languages, such as Python.

One could return an instance of this genericized class which is easily re-usable:

```
public class TypedTuple<L, R> implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  protected L left;
  protected R right;

  protected TypedTuple() {
    // Default constructor for serialization
  }

  public TypedTuple(L inLeft, R inRight) {
    left = inLeft;
    right = inRight;
  }

  public L getLeft() {
    return left;
  }

  public R getRight() {
    return right;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's sometimes nice to have a generic static method `create()`, to avoid having to specify the type parameters in the constructor.  Also, I would name this class `Pair` rather than `Tuple`, given it can only represent 2-tuples of values.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that this class is taking responsibility away from another class, and this makes me think that this design isn't great.

For a method that returns multible values, I would rather

- return a generic containter (e.g. a List or Map) containing the return values

or

- create a Class for the return value, which contains just of the necessary fields + getters + a constructor with all fields

Example for the second option:

```
public Class FooBarRetval {
   private String foo;
   private int bar;

   public FooBarRetval (String foo, int bar) {
      this.foo = foo;
      this.bar = bar;
   }

   public String getFoo() {
      return foo;
   }

   public int getBar() {
      return bar;
   }
}
```

Comment: Making the fields public adds the option of altering the values separately, though clearly the values have a relation (otherwise they would not have to be returned by the same method). I would highly discourage this pattern in this special situation. But the main point is, the discussion of public vs. private attributes has nothing to do with OPs question and I see no reason for the last sentence in an otherwise good answer.

Comment: The first one should be preferred.

Comment: scarfridge: Point taken, last sentence removed.

Comment: Just use public final fields, no reason to waste time with accessors.

Answer (score 1):

Putting multiple return values from a method into its own class/structure is often used in [message based systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-based) that have one class for 
[Request and response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request-response). An example of this is  [Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP).

> Is it a good design and why?

At least it is quite common. If this is good or bad depends on your special usecase.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can return an array or a List with the two values.

I personally would write two distinct methods, like

```
int x = obj.getX();
int y = obj.getY();
```