# When to use xxxResult return value pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have one method which need to return multiple values whether it was successful or not, what the key used to call the api and if successful the return result. Here is more concrete method,

```
public xxxResult PublishMessage(){

   // dynamically calculate the key
   try {
         // call the third party api and get the result
         // return key-used, result and successful flag
   }
   catch(Exception ex){
      // return key-used, null result and not-successful flag
   }
}
```

Is it make sense to create a xxxResult class here or is there any other way design that I missing here? When should we use xxxResult pattern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A way to return multiple return values from a method: put method inside class representing return value. Is it a good design?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166908/a-way-to-return-multiple-return-values-from-a-method-put-method-inside-class-re)

Comment: @gnat: Not even close. That question is very general. The aspect of calling an external web API means the answers to the possible duplicate don't apply.

Comment: Is the PublishMessage method part of a service layer in the application, or some sort of "use case?" How close is this code to the user interface?

Comment: @GregBurghardt PublishMessage is a event client like Sns pub/sub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hate xxxResult / xxxReponse classes. Its just bad naming

They normally seem to appear when you are serialising a response to a json object to pass back from a REST API and want to include some meta data, such as an error occuring as well as the actual result.

But there are better ways of handling this senario, namely returning a HTTP error code and an error message instead of a result.

In your particular case I would seperate the key generation and message publishing concerns to avoid the compound return type and to avoid the problem of an actual crash rather than an exception meaning you lose a key

Other cases I've seen are where you do have a legitimate 'Result of a Proccess' complex Type which really has no meaning on its own. Here you just need to get more inventive with your naming if you want to avoid many xxxResult classes.

The ReportGenerationResult is a Report, the ToolCalibrationResult is an ErrorMeasurement etc

Comment: how to tell the method invoker whether api was successful or not? If successful then the result

Comment: if successful HTTP code 200 + json. if not 500 and error message in body

Comment: You mean I should return HttpResponse?

Comment: if you are using HTTP then you have no choice. If its just local methods you can just throw an exception

Comment: Its Aws SnsClient

Comment: what is? the whole thing? with thier PublishRequest PublishResponse, DeleteTopicRequest etc? I would return  or throw an exception rather than have those ugly classes

Answer (score 5):

If your language supports **tuples**, this may be a solution. Tuples have several benefits in this case:

- The method is easier to write.

  ```
  try {
      return (true, obj);
  } catch (...) {
      return (false, null);
  }
  ```
- The caller code is simpler as well.

  ```
  var success, response = PublishMessage();
  ```
- There is no need to create an additional class.

If the language doesn't support tuples, **your other option is to have the method return one type on success, another type on failure**. The caller will have to check the type of the returned value, and act accordingly for one type or another.

```
try {
    return new Key(...);
} catch (...) {
    return new ApiError(...);
}
```

**Yet another solution is to have a magical value**: say `null` to indicate an error. While simpler than the previous approach, **I wouldn't recommend it**. Having two types makes it possible to extend the response later. For instance, the response returned on error can contain the error code or the error message.

Comment: If failure means no response, and a response means success, there's no need for a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a little polymorphism. This

```
public xxxResult PublishMessage(){

   // dynamically calculate the key
   try {
         // call the third party api and get the result
         // return key-used, result and successful flag
   }
   catch(Exception ex){
      // return key-used, null result and not-successful flag
   }
}
```

can become

```
public Message PublishMessage(){
   Message message; 

   // dynamically calculate the key
   Key key = calculateKey();

   try {
         // call the third party api and get the result
         APIResult apiResult = thirdPartyAPI.getResult();

         // return key-used, result and successful flag
         message = new MessageSuccess(key, apiResult);
   }
   catch(Exception ex){
      // return key-used, null result and not-successful flag
      message = new MessageFailure(key);
   }
   finally{
       return message;
   } 
}
```

The caller will **NOT** have to check the type of the returned value. Whatever code is using this doesn't have to know or care what happened. The exception has been handled and the message itself will know what to do and has everything it needs to do it. One way or the other.

But please use better names than these.